# MQTT message from csv file

Tags: python, csv, mqtt, iot

I have a csv file and I need to send this file as a MQTT message, but I need it to sending just by one line with a few seconds of break and then next line and again a few sec break. It's something like sensor simulation but with data in csv file. I've tried to solve it in several different ways but nothing worked. I'm coding in Python. Thank you guys for any help. Code here is my latest attempt and after running the function MQTT_publish() I'm receiving messages with 5 sec break but in every message is whole file, not just one line. Ireally don't know what to do with it.

```
def MQTT_publish(broker, file, topic):
  client = mqtt.Client()
  print("Connecting to broker", broker)
  client.connect(broker)
  client.loop_start()
  print("Publishing...")

  client.loop_start()
  with open(file, 'r') as read_obj:
      data = reader(read_obj)
      for row in data:
          client.publish(f"{topic}", str(row))
          time.sleep(5)
  client.loop_stop()

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
  print(str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")))


def MQTT_subscribe(broker, topic):
  client = mqtt.Client()
  print("Connecting to broker", broker)
  client.connect(broker)

  print(f"Subscribing {topic}")
  client.subscribe(f"{topic}")
  client.on_message = on_message
  client.loop_forever()

broker = "mqtt.eclipse.org"
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your code to show what you have tried and what you are currently using ?

Comment: I added my code in the question. This is the last try what i did.

Comment: Where is `broker` coming from and what error do you get ?

Comment: Maybe your `time.sleep(10)` instruction should be in the loop over the rows ?

Comment: @Frodon I threw time.sleep(10) into the loop and it didn't change anything unfortunately:(

Comment: When I run the function with broker = 'mqtt.eclipse.org', I don't have any error but in messages I don't have lines but whole file is sending in the loop.

Comment: Please edit the question to provide a few lines of example input so we have something to test with.

Comment: @hardillb is it okay now?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you be using readlines()??

```
myfile = open(file, 'r')
Lines = myfile.readline()
for line in Lines:
  client.publish(f"{topic}", str(line.strip()))
  time.sleep(5)
```

This is assuming that the data in the file is ASCII with linefeeds.

Comment: It is still sending the entire file as a message:(

Comment: @py1527 Then your file has no linefeeds, or is formatted in such a way that the readline() function can't determine where one line stops and another line starts. How are the lines terminated?  What is the demark that you want to use to break up your messages?